# How Can I Create Formula with my MYSQL Query Result

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports-2008

How to Subtract every two column in crystal report using edit formula timeend - timestart with this format hh:mm:ss

Just like my query result

```
SELECT timestart, timeend, TIMEDIFF(timeend, timestart) AS rangetime 
FROM time;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take below query in `command` while making the connection to the crystal reports.

   ```
   SELECT timestart, timeend FROM time;
   ```
2. In crystal reports place `timestart` and `timeend` in the detail section of the report.
3. Now create a formula `@Difference` and write below code.

   ```
   timeend-timestart; //Assuming timestart and timeend are in seconds you need to convert into HH,MM and SS format.
   CTime(HH,M,SS);
   ```
4. Place the formula after `timeend` in the detail section